# Binary Tree's usage

Tags: binary-tree

Can someone give me a real life example ( in programming, C#) of needing to use a Binary Tree or even just an ordinary tree?

I understand the principle of a Binary Tree and how they work, but I'm trying to find some real life example's of their usage?

Tony

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the applications of binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, Java, Python, C++ (using the STL) and other high-level languages, most of the time you will use one of the built-in/library-included types to store your data, at least the data you work on at the moment, so most of the time you won't be using a binary tree or another kind of tree explicitly.

This being said, some of these built-in types are implemented as trees of one kind or another "in the backstage", and in some situations you will have to implement one yourself.

Also, a related thing you HAVE to know is binary search. This is mostly done in binary trees (binary search trees :P) but the idea can be extrapolated to a lot of problems, even without trees involved, so try understand it well.

Edit: Real life classical example:

Imagine that you want to search for the phone number of a particular person in the phone guide of a big city. All things being equal, you will open it roughly at the middle, look for the guys in that page, and see if your "target" is before or after it, thus cutting the data by half. Then you repeat the operation in the half where you know your "target" is, and again and again until you found your "target". As each time you are looking into half the data you had before, you require a total of log(base 2) n operations to reach your "target", where n is the total size of the data.

So in a 1 million phone book, you find your target in log(base 2) 1 million = 20 comparisons, instead of comparing one by one as in a linear search (that's 1 million comparisons in the worst case).

Note that this only work in already sorted data.

Answer (score 4):

[Balanced binary trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), storing data maintained **in sorted order**, are used to achieve O(log(n)) lookup, delete, and insert times. "Balanced" just means there is a bounded limit between the depth of the shallowest and deepest leaves, counting empty left/right nodes as leaves. (optimally the depth of left and right subtrees differs at most by one, some implementations relax this to make the algorithms simpler)

You can use an array, rather than a tree, in sorted order with binary search to achieve O(log(n)) lookup time, but then the insert/delete times are O(n).

Some trees (notably [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for databases) use more than 2 branches per node, to widen the tree and reduce the maximum depth (which determines search times).

<strike>I can't think of a reason to use binary trees that are not maintained in sorted order (a point that has not been mentioned in most of the answers here), but maybe there's some application for this.</strike> Besides the sorted binary balanced tree, anything with hierarchy (as other answerers have mentioned, XML or directory structures) is a good application for trees, whether binary or not.

**edit:** re: unsorted binary trees: I just remembered that LISP and Scheme both make heavy use of unbalanced binary trees. The `cons` function takes two arguments (e.g. `(define c (cons a b))` ) and returns a tree node whose branches are the two arguments. The `car` function takes such a tree node and returns the first argument given to `cons`. The `cdr` function is similar but returns the second argument to `cons`. Finally `nil` represents a null object. These are the primitives used to make all data structures in LISP and Scheme. Lists are implemented using an extreme unbalanced binary tree. The list containing literal elements `'Alabama`, `'Alaska`, `'Arizona`, and `'Arkansas` can be constructed explicitly as

```
(cons 'Alabama (cons 'Alaska (cons 'Arizona (cons 'Arkansas nil))))
```

and can be traversed using `car` and `cdr` (where `car` is used to get the head of the list and `cdr` is used to get the sublist excluding the list head). This is how Scheme works, I think LISP is the same or very similar. More complicated data structures, like binary trees (which need 3 members per node: two to hold the left and right nodes, and a third to hold the node value) or trees containing more than two branches per node can be constructed using a list to implement each node.

Answer (score 3):

How about the directory structure in Unix. For instance the du command i.e. the disk usage command does a post order traversal (traversal order:: left child -> right child -> root node) of a tree representing the directory structure in order to fetch the disk space used by that directory.

The following slides should help.

http://www.cse.unt.edu/~rada/CSCE3110/Lectures/Trees.ppt

cheers

Comment: great example -- although directory structures are not binary trees

Comment: yes, they are not binary trees. I just posted this as Tony mentioned ordinary tree in his question.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, trees are used to implement certain sorted data structures, such as the TreeSet:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

They are used for data structures where you want the order to be based on some property of the elements, rather than on insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples:

- The in-memory representation of a parsed program or expression is a tree.  In the case of expressions (excluding ternary operators) the tree will be binary.
- The components of a GUI are organized as a tree.
- Any "containment" hierarchy can be represented as a tree.  (HTML, XML and SGML are examples.

And of course, binary (and n-ary) trees can be used to represent indexes, maps, sets and other "generic" data structures.

Answer (score 0):

An easy example is searching. If you store your list data in a tree, for example, you get O(log(n)) lookup times. A standard array implementation of a list would achieve O(n) lookup time.

Comment: So you can store anything you'd store in an array in a tree too?  But in a tree the lookup time is less... I guess that only comes into play with data structures containing lots of data.

Comment: @Tony: Not necessarily. Anything with an explicit hierarchy is well-suited for trees (maybe not binary trees, but certainly trees in general) even if it's not that many items. (Consider your family tree: even if you don't know that many of your relatives it's still a tree!)

Comment: A binary search tree requires **O**(log2 *n*) compares.  A linear list requires **O**(*n*/2).  At 8 elements, you'll find that the tree requires (at most) 3 compares but the linear search requires (on average) 4.

Comment: A linear list REQUIRES n comparisons, although given a perfectly random list distribution, you find your element in n/2 comparisons. Please don't abuse big-O notation. Furthermore, the base of the log is dependent on nodes per level, which is why I left off the two. No one said anything about binary trees.

Comment: Just to be clear, O(n/2) = O(n), and O(log_2(n)) = O(log_k(n))

Answer (score 0):

XML, HTML (and SGML) documents are trees.

Comment: But they aren't binary trees ? Because they may have more than two children that belong to one node, so it doesn't comply with the binary tree rules.

Comment: They are n-ary trees, with any node may have an arbitrary number of child nodes.  It's used for flexibility (so your HTML document can have any structure), where a binary tree and it's cousins (red/black, etc) are built to store large amounts of data and insert or retrieve any data item very quickly relative to the number of things stored in the tree.

Comment: Hmmm- Now I can't remember if n-ary tree is the right term.  The rest of my description is OK, though.

Comment: n-ary tree sounds reasonable, if there is a more widely used term I can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: You can build n-ary trees from binary tree nodes.  Your binary tree has "sibling" and "child" links.  The sibling links create a kind of linked list.

Comment: But you should not build n-ary trees from binary tree nodes. Both from a space and a performance point of view.