# real world examples for binary tree structure

Tags: data-structures

Can any one tell me some real world examples of binary tree structure ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the applications of binary trees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees)

Answer (score 2):

Binary trees are used all over the place in the real world.  Pretty much every major implementation of a sorted data-structure uses one (usually a balanced variant, like red-black).

In C++, map and set are built on it.

Answer (score 0):

Represent a uni-dimensional space.

I don't know world examples other than this one.

But it's large used for logical purposes and indexers.

Answer (score 0):

- Databases indexes. When you index a field, it is put in a binary tree for fast retrieval.
- General Searching/sorting. A binary search tree will let you sort and search for data quickly

Answer (score 0):

I believe Huffman Algorithm also use Binary tree!!!