# What are binary trees and why are they useful?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the applications of binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees)

What are binary trees? Why are they useful? Why do some STL containers use them for storing elements? Why is the time required to search a tree O(log *n*)?

Comment: Also see [What are the applications of binary trees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees).