# How do the native JavaScript types get written in Elm?

Tags: javascript, tree, functor, elm, algebraic-data-types

How do the native JavaScript types get written in Elm?  The files defining `List` are surprisingly short and easy to read:

- [List.elm](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/List.elm)
- [Native/List.js](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Native/List.js)

I am curious of how Elm does it's job of proving a type-safe interface to JavaScript.  Is the JavaScript written by hand, or is it compiled from another language like Haskell?

---

#### Elm's `List` Type

The key line of Elm seems to be ...

```
module List exposing
  ( isEmpty, length, reverse, member
  , head, tail, filter, take, drop
  , repeat, (::), append, concat
  )

import Basics exposing (..)
import Maybe
import Maybe exposing ( Maybe(Just,Nothing) )
import Native.List

(::) : a -> List a -> List a
(::) = Native.List.cons

infixr 5 ::

head : List a -> Maybe a
head list =
  case list of
    x :: xs ->
      Just x

    [] ->
      Nothing

tail : List a -> Maybe (List a)
tail list =
  case list of
    x :: xs ->
      Just xs

    [] ->
      Nothing
```

This tells us that `head` and `tail` can be defined within Elm, but `(::)` operation must be defined with JavaScript.  Here are some key lines in JavaScript to have to do with the constructor:

```
var _elm_lang$core$Native_List = function() {

var Nil = { ctor: '[]' };

function Cons(hd, tl) { return { ctor: '::', _0: hd, _1: tl }; }

...

return {
    Nil: Nil,
    Cons: Cons,

    // etc
};

}();
```

I am especially curious about the line `{ ctor: '::', _0: hd, _1: tl };` since the word **ctor** is the second half of the word **functor** -- which may mean a functor was written in JavaScript.

---

These considerations are important because I am considering writing a `Tree a` and/or [`QuadTree a`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quadtree) type and it might be good to write from inside Elm (e.g. using Records) or to write a module for personal use.

- one implementation of tree could just have nodes
- another could distinguish [between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees) **Left** and **Right** nodes
- another just has **4** indistinguishable nodes.

Another example could be [`CircularList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-list) but I just want to focus on trees for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is that the implementation of `List` is written in Javascript primarily because its constructors are `[]` and `::`, but Elm doesn't allow for infix operators as constructor names.

For example, the way we use `List` in Elm means the definition really should be something like this:

```elm
type List a = ([]) | (::) a (List a)
```

That doesn't compile in Elm even though we pattern match on those constructors, so the shortcut of using Javascript to define the implementation is used.

If you write your own custom list implementation with different names, the javascript output is the same as the javascript implementation of `List`.

```elm
type MyList a = MyNil | MyCons a (MyList a)
```

... yields ...

```js
var _user$project$Temp1467112617033056$MyCons = F2(
  function (a, b) {
    return {ctor: 'MyCons', _0: a, _1: b};
  });
var _user$project$Temp1467112617033056$MyNil = {ctor: 'MyNil'};
```

Therefore, I don't see any reason why your proposed `Tree` or `QuadTree` types would benefit from being written in a Native javascript module. I'd recommend writing them in Elm.

Comment: I found this example of `BinaryTree` on Elm's examples page http://elm-lang.org/examples/binary-tree

Answer (score 3):

I *think* `ctor` is short for "constructor" and the `List` is just implemented as a linked list. Each node is either the empty list (`{ ctor: '[]' }`) or is made of a value (at `_0`) and the rest of the list (at `_1`) put together with the `'::'` constructor.

Ex the list `[1, 2]` would be `Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))` which fully expanded would be

```js
{ ctor: '::',
  _0: 1,
  _1: { ctor: '::',
        _0: 2,
        _1: { ctor: '[]' } } }
```

You can see in the [`toArray`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Native/List.js#L22) function that it is using `xs.ctor !== '[]'` to check if it has reached the end of the list, or if it should push the head on to the array and keep going.

```js
function toArray(xs)
{
    var out = [];
    while (xs.ctor !== '[]')
    {
        out.push(xs._0);
        xs = xs._1;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: a linked list of length 1000 would be very nested. unless they use pointers

Comment: I don't think there are any optimizations for large lists. The `Array` type is supposed to be more performant and there was even a proposal to switch the default collection from `List` to `Array` citing performance as the #1 reason https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-plans/issues/13

Comment: oh wow is there a trade-off between being immutable and being fast? http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.12.1 Elm is very much a work in progress, I still like it very much