# Interview prep - How does one access nodes in binary search trees in the real world?

Tags: search, data-structures, iterator, binary-tree

I'm preparing for the data structures portion of an interview. I see that there are already questions about applications of binary trees in the real world - [What are the applications of binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees)

My question is different - **How does one actually access nodes in data structures based on trees?**

I understand BFS, DFS and such for explicit node traversal, I get a sense this is not how the real world works. Do people write their own traversal / search algorithms, or do they rely on iterators and similar access methods provided by the database?

**What is the name of a high level abstraction of accessing structured tree data, if any?**  I'm thinking of iterators, but am not sure if this is the right term.

I am looking for a way to intelligently converse on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the name of a high level abstraction of accessing structured
>   tree data, if any?

`Iterator` is something more suitable for linear data-structure like linked list or dynamic array. As tree is a hierarchical data-structure, `parent()`, `child()`, `children()`, `ancestor()`, `descendent()` are more suitable. For instance, if you want to implement a file system, you will have `RootDirectory` and to get all the sub-directories you might call like `getAllSubDirectories()` which are actually children of root directory. So the naming is actually domain specific.

```
class Directory {
   private Integer someAttribute;
   ....
   ....
   private Directory parentDirectory;
   List<Directory> subDirectories;
}
```

You can abstract as iterator and can call `iterator.hasNext()` or `iterator.next()` on a hierarchical data-structure as well. So for example, for a binary search tree, you can abstract away an iterator which can iterate the tree in preorder/inorder/postorder traversal in both direction. See [in-order successor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).